# Integrating New Relic with Celery

Tags: centos, celery, centos7, newrelic

I am trying to configure New Relic to work with Celery.  I am working on a Django application hosted on Amazon EC2 w/ CentOS 7.

I thought all I needed to do to configure New Relic for celery was to edit the following line in /etc/systemd/system/celery.service  :

`ExecStart=/home/myuser/project/venv/bin/celery -A project worker -l info -c 4`

and change it to:

`ExecStart=/home/myuser/project/newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program celery -A project worker -l info -c 4`

But I see the following errors:

```sh
[root@ip-172-31-60-222 system]# systemctl daemon-reload
[root@ip-172-31-60-222 system]# systemctl restart celery
[root@ip-172-31-60-222 system]# systemctl status celery.service -l
● celery.service - datasidekick celery service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2017-03-01 04:16:33 UTC; 900ms ago
  Process: 22969 ExecStart=/home/datasidekick/datasidekick/newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program /home/datasidekick/datasidekick/venv/bin/celery -A datasidekick worker -l info -c 4 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 22969 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 01 04:16:33 ip-172-31-60-222.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit celery.service entered failed state.
Mar 01 04:16:33 ip-172-31-60-222.ec2.internal systemd[1]: celery.service failed.
Mar 01 04:16:33 ip-172-31-60-222.ec2.internal systemd[1]: celery.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 01 04:16:33 ip-172-31-60-222.ec2.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for celery.service
Mar 01 04:16:33 ip-172-31-60-222.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start datasidekick celery service.
Mar 01 04:16:33 ip-172-31-60-222.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit celery.service entered failed state.
Mar 01 04:16:33 ip-172-31-60-222.ec2.internal systemd[1]: celery.service failed.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you asked the question but the reason of the fail is probably the wrong `ExecStart` command.

You use `/home/myuser/project/newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program celery -A project worker -l info -c 4` as the command to start the service. The first part of the command will try to execute `/home/myuser/project/newrelic.ini`, which is a text file, and fail with `Permission denied` error as text files don't have exec permission by default. Or it will cause a bash syntax error somewhere and fail as well.

Insead, use

```
Environment="NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=/home/myuser/project/newrelic.ini"
ExecStart=newrelic-admin run-program celery -A project worker -l info -c 4
```

Answer (score -1):

run `journalctl -u celery -f`and paste logs here
also have look at this links

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/back-end-services/python-agent-celery

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/need-some-help-setting-up-new-relic-with-our-celery-workers/30181